# css group elements with same content

Tags: css

I have multiple CSS sheets with the same class name. I want to group elements with the same class for use with the correct class into my `<div>` elements and not add `.example` in every element, ei:

CSS :

```
 .example input{...}
    .example textarea{...}
    .example a{...}
    .example div{...}
```

I don't want to repeat `.example` for every element.

```
 .example{
        input{...}
        textarea{...}
        a{...}
        div{...}
     }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You must tell the browser the parent before the child. One thing that might help though, is if you're applying the same styles to every child element, then you could use `.example *` which will target every child element of an `.example` node.

If you don't want to target everything (i.e. you need to make anchors follow the style, but not paragraphs) then you'll need to do it long hand.

```
.example a, 
.example input, 
.example textarea,
.example div,
/*Whatever else you need specifically*/ {}
```

Comment: my problem is that i will need add .example for eache element into an extensive style.css, you have other idea for do that?

Comment: I need separate class with same name in diferent style sheets, the first css if for the template and the second is for a plugin

Comment: From your original question, it sounds like you don't want to add a class. How do you know the elements are related then?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like:

```
input, textarea, a, div {...}
```

And then

```
input{...}
textarea{...}
a{...}
div{...}
```

Comment: This will not only target `.example` children, but all of those elements on the page. The OP will still need to have `.example input, .example textarea`...